# Word for 'update progress'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

I want to name a button, in an app, that opens a window where the user can update a book's progress (in terms of pages, like 10 or 20 pages). Can someone tell a more appropriate name for that button?

Comment: First, what don't you like about *update progress*? (I don't believe there is a *single* word that means the combination of those two things.)

Comment: Thanks, @JasonBassford for replying. I was not very confident using 'update progress' because it sounds a bit technical. I searched for synonyms but couldn't find any suitable one. I think you are right, maybe there is no better word for it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Please provide an English context (sentence or paragraph) for [tag:single-word-requests]. A single-word-request without an English context may be considered off-topic. Consider using an appropriate icon for a button.

Comment: Is the user reading a book? If so, would *pages read* work? A name specific to your app may work better than a more general name.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're looking for "table of contents".  Or, if you want to mark where you are so you can find it later, "bookmarks".

Comment: *" the user can update a book's progress (in terms of pages, like 10 or 20 pages)."*  I don't understand what you mean by "a book's progress". Where is the book going? Is the user writing the book? If so, the usual word is "save". Is the user reading the book? Your question is not clear.

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not aware of any single words of this meaning, if you don't like "update progress" you could consider these alternatives:
Instead of update, you could use **amend**, **alter**, or even **edit** if you see fit. 
As for progress, you could use **completion status** or **advancement**.

Comment: I'm downvoting because the OP hasn't explained what sort of progress they are talking about (reading, writing, order status, etc.). We can't answer unless they explain.

Answer (score -1):

How about **extend**, **enhance**, **enrich** or simply **update**?

I personally would use update, since it's commonly used on buttons and allows the possibility of fixing or even removing work.

Comment: Just update could mean update book details like name, author, total pages. Thanks, but it seems I have to go with 'update progress'

Comment: *"Just update could mean update book details like name, author, total pages"* Yes it could but you haven't explained what *you* mean by "update progress"*. What sort of progress?

Comment: I'm downvoting because the OP hasn't explained what sort of progress they are talking about (reading, writing, order status, etc.). We can't answer unless they explain.